# Vector Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I have a vector storing struct, and I pass it by address to a function. I wonder why I can only access to the elements by writing

> ```
> (*v)[0].value
> ```

instead of

> ```
> v[0].value
> ```

When I use struct array, and pass it to a function by address, I can simply write

v[0].value to get the value of an element. Any explanation is welcomed and thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass it by reference instead of pass by pointer. This is the reason c++ has pass by reference(unlike `C`) so that you won't have to dereference things everywhere.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also post the error you're getting. We can't answer based on guesses about what the error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing a pointer *to the first element* of an array to a pointer to the *whole* vector.

Let's try to make a pointer to the whole array instead of its first element:

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int (*ap)[3] = &a;
// int v1 = ap[0]; // error
int v2 = (*ap)[0]; // ok
```

Which is exactly like how a pointer to a vector behaves:

```
std::vector<int> b = {1,2,3};
std::vector<int> *bp = &b;
// int v3 = bp[0]; // error
int v4 = (*bp)[0]; // ok
```

Or, the other way around, let's make a pointer to the first element of a vector:

```
std::vector<int> c = {1,2,3};
int *cp = c.data(); // or `&c[0]`
int v5 = cp[0]; // ok
```

Which is similar to a pointer to the first element of an array:

```
int d[3] = {1,2,3};
int *dp = d; // or `&d[0]`
int v6 = dp[0]; // ok
```

Comment: Why does using 'vector<mytype>* v' as an argument at the function mean a pointer to the whole vector? However, 'int* a' as an argument means a pointer to the first element? I thought the syntax look almost the same, so they should have the same meaning.

Comment: @高造擎 It depends on the context. `vector<mytype> *v` is a pointer to a vector, and `int *a` is a pointer to an `int`, and that's all. Both can point to a single object, or they can point to an element of an array/vector of similar objects.

Comment: @HollyBlackCat amazing explanation, thank you so much. You clarify everything for me.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the struct that you have is named `yourtype`.

##### Case 1

The type of the expression `(*v)[0]` is `yourtype` which has a member called `value` so we're allowed to write `(*v)[0].value`.

##### Case 2

In this case, the type of the expression `v[0]` is `vector<yourtype>` and since `vector<yourtype>` doesn't have any member called `value`, we're not allowed to write `v[0].value` and we will get an error here saying exactly this:

```
error: ‘class std::vector’ has no member named ‘value’
```

---

Also, you should pass the vector **by reference** instead of a pointer to that vector. This is one of the reason why C++ has pass by reference(unlike `C`) so that you don't have to dereference things everywhere.